# Why don't computers use centimetres?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web, operating-system

I have a question why don't computers use centimetres (or inches)  instead of pixels?

I started thinking about this and I don't see why practically everything is not measured in centimetres or other real life units of measurement. Pixels are not a real unit of measurement (pixel != pixel).

If we go to HTML the resulting web page can have a drastically different look or be unreadable if text size is defined in pixels (I know that pixels are not recommended for specifying text size).

However why not use centimetres ? You define the size of the font in centimetres and the reading device looks up how many pixels correspond to a centimetre (closest approximation) and converts the result into pixels. Its a simple operation and the user will always see a readable text like it was intended for display regardless of the pixel density of their screen.

This concept can be expanded so that GUI elements (OS, applications, HTML web page navigation) are specified in centimetres and are made out of vector graphics so that they will always look the same size regardless of the monitor they are displayed on.

The question I have is why are no real measurements used in computers especially web pages (HTML,CSS), OS and applications ? What is preventing the move forward and the use of real sizes?

Comment: You can use `em` as a measuring unit for fonts. it will look the same on all monitors, just like vectors.

Comment: And not a single thought for the poor inches?

Comment: Because one inch on a 19" monitor is much different than one inch on a 100" projection.  But if you measure by pixels, it scales properly.

Comment: You CAN use `cm`, `mm` and `in` for HTML sizes.

Comment: @Joan.bdm, you CAN, but it is not recommended  in the W3C specs.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin yeah I know, it'll be a pain in the ass using them actually.

Comment: What is the question? Computers surely use centimeters if told to (say, with `font-size: 5cm` in CSS). To the extent that there is a real question involved (like “why don’t people use the `cm` unit in CSS more?”), it’s probably too broad or primarily opinion-based or both.

Answer (score 2):

Pixels allow a very fine level of control over a display and allow for a cross-device method for displaying graphical data.

There is a measurement known as PPI (pixels per inch), also known as pixel density. This is because a pixel definition or implementation may not be the same across all devices.

By using pixels, the displays can be calculated for the user's device whereas centimetres or inches are static.

If you used centimetres for a display, it may look good on your monitor but it would look very different on a small device such as a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Computers are essentially machines that use digital information in discreet quantities. The smallest unit of measure for a screen or monitor is the pixel, much like the atom is the smallest practical division of matter in the analog world.

Monitors may also have varying degrees of resolution (the number of pixels per unit length, referred to as DPI or Dots Per Inch in the old days) and depth (the number of different colors any individual pixel could be, typically a power of 2. "8-bit" color meant 2 to the 8th = 256 different colors per pixel, whereas "32-bit" would mean over 4 billion different colors). One of the very first widely used screen resolutions was 72 DPI ~= 183 dots-per-centimeter with only 8-bit color.

Also, a linear measurement standard might not result in an integer quantity. For example, if your pixel aperture was not exactly 1/10th of a centimeter (or 1/x, x any number you want) then there would be no way to accurately express the size of any object on the screen in discrete units. For example, if the screen density was such that there were exactly 439 pixels per 2 centimeters, calculations for pixels-to-linear measurements would be very cumbersome.

Comment: I don't think that errors <1mm are important. If the page/image/gui/whatever approximates cm with a ~1mm error rate its not a real problem. 

In manufacturing  fault tolerances or building in a given precision are common. Besides isn’t that the manufacturers problem if his device is inferior? 

One can criticise RGB (or any technology) on the same basis since it will not display on a black and white monitor.

Comment: I like to point out that monitors with a color depth of "8-bit" will not display correctly "32-bit" color. Is this an argument against ever using "32-bit" color because some devices from the old days might have problems with them ? The same is true for cm measurements.

Comment: I, of course, had nothing to do with any of the industry standards. The one thing about errors: they propagate and get larger, rather than self correct. Starting with an "atom model" with an indivisible unit, error propagation is mitigated. Clever software and hardware implementation still had to deal with "grayscale" and "dithering" operations in the 1980s. This would occur when a printing device, like a LaserPrinter @300 dpi resolution tried to print a screen image, @ 72 dpi resolution. This led to "bitmap" images evolving to "vectorized" format, then encapsulated post script (eps) was born.

Comment: Besides what is your point here ? That ~1mm error is unacceptable however using pixels that can have 50% size errors (depending on the device its 2 cm and on another the same picture is 1 cm ) are OK ? What is less bad ~1mm error or a 1cm error ? From your calculation 439 px = 2 cm; 1px = 0.004555808656036446469248291571754 cm; 2px=0.009111617312072892938496583142 cm; rounding up 2px = 0.01 cm; a error of 0.001 cm is not a problem you are not making a electron microscope here. You assume that 0.01cm = 2 px for your device.

Comment: I mention all of that because "things change." There was no need to think about 300 dpi printers when 72 dpi screen resolution was all any monitor vendor could supply. Now with laser printers far outpacing the resolution of any display device, requiring a retro-fit to a metric scale of centimeters would have a disastrous impact. The correct standard was chosen at the foundation stage of the industry: pixels = the fundamental unit. That is not going to change any time soon.